# Can anything be done to fix the lag in Terraria Multiplayer?

Tags: terraria

Single player runs just fine, but multiplayer seems to lag for me and my two friends. It doesn't matter who hosts it.

Our computers are fairly decent - good video cards, cpu, lots of ram, etc, but Terraria still seems to lag for us.

I've seen some solutions online to limit framerate, adjust processor affinity, change priority of executable, etc but nothing seems to us. Actually adjusting the processor affinity / framerate worked for me, but not my friends.

Does anyone know what else we can try? Or can what is causing the lag in the first place?

Comment: What kind of online connections do you have? Lag might be limited more by upload / download rates as well as poor specs (and Terraria is not a terribly graphics intensive game)

Comment: we have verizon fios so its something like 50mb down, 5/up. I'm not positive the exact numbers, but its good

Comment: In the 1.0.6 release of Terraria, the [changelog](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/1-0-6-changelog.50278/) mentions the following performance update: _Optimized "Finding Tile Frames", so worlds should load faster_. If this was causing lag for you before, you may notice an improvement now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How are you running the server?

I've run a server on a computer and port-forwarded the ports and had very bad lag issues with friends directly connecting. However, when I run it and my friends connect through [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/download.aspx), it seems to alleviate most of the lag. If you're not running through Hamachi, you should give it a try.

This seems counter-intuitive to me since you would think Hamachi would ADD overhead, not take it away but what can I say, that's what I've noticed.

Comment: I will give that a try,thanks. We are running it through a router with port forwarding

Comment: @Rachel: Good luck!

Comment: If anyone cares, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxJplRcRakQ is a good walkthrough of setting up Hamachi

Comment: Lag is a bit better with Hamachi, but still bad with flying enemies or projectiles

Comment: @Rachel: The only other thing I can think of is if you have other things running on your computer or on your LAN. Sometimes I have issues when my roommates are downloading torrents or large files. Either that or you are physically far away from your friends, if that's the case it may cause it to be laggy, though *you* should not experience too much lag. If you're all laggy as well, it's probably because your computer is too slow to handle the server and client at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

are you running other apps that takes up your bandwidth? if yes try closing them and running on slightly more RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The game may work better if you set your monitor's refresh rate to 60 Hz and turn frameskip off in the Terraria settings menu. At least worked for me. I use dedicated server.

This fixes an issue where the server and the client have different framerate (speed) for the game.

Comment: Thanks, but those settings are already set

Answer (score 0):

We had some lag, but disabling CPU 1 in affinity of the server or client helped it run smoothly.