# Can't get onto my brother's server, and vice versa, across local network in Terraria

Tags: technical-issues, terraria, hosting, server-administration

I have a similar problem to [Shadow Z, in his original question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63118/how-do-i-join-multiplayer-servers-in-terraria)

My problem differs, however, since I have already followed the instructions to set up my MQWest modem for port forwarding. I also do not need Hamachi, since I'm already on the same LAN network as my brother. I've already tried everything suggested, before, but nothing works.

My main question is how do I check if Terraria can access data from the forwarded port, but I also want to know if there is anything else I could try. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Random info, in case if any of it can help solve my problem.

Router IP: 192.168.0.1

Port Number: 7777

Modem Brand: MyQwest

Computer: Shuttle desktop, with Windows XP

Btother's Computer: Dell laptop, with Windows 10

We are both using bandwith, connected to the same router.

Comment: I am confused by what you say. The question you link **not only provides an adequate guide to ensuring your ports are forwarded, but there is also an alternate solution that circumnavigates port forwarding, entirely.** In essence, you have posted a duplicate question, referencing the question you are duplicating.

Comment: I'm marking this as unclear because you haven't provided any additional information to differentiate your problem from the linked problem. If you have the same problem then follow the answer in that question. If it's similar and you've already tried the other solution then you'll have to provide some more information.

Comment: I've added that I've already had my ports forwarded, following all the instructions given before. I also do not need Hamachi since I'm already on the same LAN network as my brother. My problem is different since I've already tried everything suggested before but nothing works. My main question is how to check if Terraria can access data from the forwarded port.

Comment: I have provided additional information, but I probably wasn't clear. My problem is that I've tried everything suggested in the link, but the "adequate guide" is not good enough, and I've already tried Hamachi.

Comment: Are you both using wireless to connect to the router?

Comment: No, we are connected using bandwidth, although my brother also has his wireless enabled.

Comment: Have you checked your brother's and your firewall settings? Often, windows will prompt you to allow/disallow connections made by a program. If you do not allow, you will not be able to see each others' hosted games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to port forward. Port forwarding enables your ISP to grant outside users access to a specific port on your router. You do not want to do this. If you have, I would recommend you **undo** this. To answer your question, if you and your brother are both on the same LAN (i.e. the same Wi-Fi network), you should be able to do as follows:

1. Client 1 (Your Brother) Opens Terraria, Opens Multiplayer, and starts a server from there, recording the address and port given/set.
2. Once Client 1 is in game, Client 2 (you) opens Multiplayer, and rather than starting a server, connects to a server.
3. Enter the information in the given format: address:port
4. Address and port should be separated by a colon (:).
5. Client 2 (you) should connect to Client 1 (your brother) over the LAN.

It's as simple as that. No port forwarding, no hosting, nothing more complicated than the integrated system. Clients on the same **L**ocal **A**rea **N**etwork s

Answer (score 2):

**If you're on the same LAN, you want to use your internal IP address, not your public one.**

When trying to find your IP address, it's common to check websites such as http://www.whatismyip.com/ which will display it for you. However, this IP address is the internet-facing one, and is only usable for connecting to users that *aren't* on the same LAN as you. To connect to other users on the *same* LAN, you need to use the IP address your router assigns you within the LAN itself.

To find your local IP on Windows, first open the Command Prompt (one possible way to do this is to open the Run dialog box with Win+R and type "cmd"). In the command prompt, type the command "ipconfig". This will provide a number of pieces of information, of which you will want to find the entry for "IPv4 Address."

Depending on your computer's setup, there may be more than one IPv4 Address. Given your router's IP address is in the format 192.168.x.x, you'll want the IPv4 address that follows the same format, which should be paired with the "Default Gateway" entry that matches your router's IP. Other possible formats exist, such as 10.x.x.x, but yours is the most common for home networks.

Whoever is hosting the server should look up this address on the host computer, and then the other person (on the same LAN) should use that address to connect to the host computer. If you want to also include players from outside your LAN, they must still use the internet-facing IP address, as found on a website such as the one mentioned above.

Comment: Considering the age of this question and the asker's last visit date, it's unlikely I'll be able to get clarification, so I'm leaving a solution to what seems like the most likely potential problem.